# Using HTML Helpers

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, html-helper

So I'm importing the namespace like so in my master page:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" %>
```

Using the helper like this:

```
<% Html.ActionLink("Home", "Home"); %>
```

But it's yelling at me:

> The name "Html" does not exist in the
>   current context...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Home", "Home") %>
```

Comment: Do you have `<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>` in the first line?

Comment: I did yeah but for some reason when I did it with a master page that had a code-behind it didn't work. Changed it though and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the syntax is

> <%=Html.ActionLink("Home", "Home")%>

1. check your webconfig, you shouldn't have to import the base MVC classes, if your using a MVC project template.
2. namespace is System.Web.Mvc

also this is a good article explaining how to create a MVC application from MS. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337884.aspx

Answer (score 0):

inherit site class from `System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage`  in `site.master.cs`

```
public partial class Site : System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

this will surely help you